# Press 'Go' button of keyboard using Android UI Automator

Tags: java, android

I am unable to press 'Go' button on searching something on Nexus 7' tablet. We don't have any text or content description for the 'Go' button on the keyboard. I tried using following -

```
//Search something say "fun"

new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Enter URL or Search & Win")).setText("fun");

getUiDevice().pressEnter(); 
OR 

getUiDevice().pressSearch(); 

Also tried :

getUiDevice().pressKeyCode(66); //for enter

getUiDevice().pressKeyCode(84); // for search
```

But this is not working.
Could anyone help me out with this.

Thanks

Comment: I have not tried a Nexus 7, but `pressEnter()` worked for me for a regular `EditText` IIRC.

Comment: My TextView is not regular EditText. It is AutoCompleteTextView.Could you suggest any method for that?

Answer (score -1):

Try using the button attribute with reference to index.

i.e :

```
UiObject cancelButton = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.Button"));
```

Answer (score -1):

To click on "Done" button with UIAutomator just try below code
use

just make sure that correct layout in which input keyboard is open is used

UiObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(LAYOUTID)).clickBottomRight();